# How can I create images for each batch using Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to make a binary classifier that classifies the following:

Class 1. Some images that I already have.

Class 2. Some images that I create from a function, using the images of class 1.

The problem is that instead of pre-creating the two classes, and then loading them, to speed up the process I would like the class 2 images to be created for each batch.

Any ideas on how I can tackle the problem? If I use the DataLoader as usual, I have to enter the images of both classes directly, but if I still don't have the images of the second class I don't know how to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to save the images of class 2 after processing or only preprocessing them and then train the model?

Comment: Well a simple way of doing it instead of datasets and loaders is a simple stack to create 1 batch via the ```torch.stack``` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tackle the problem in at least two ways.

1. (Preferred) You create a custom `Dataset` class, `AugDset`, such that `AugDset.__len__()` returns `2 * len(real_dset)`, and when `idx > len(imgset)`, `AugDset.__getitem__(idx)` generates the synthetic image from `real_dset(idx)`.
2. You create your custom `collate_fn` function, to be passed to `DataLoader` that, given a batch, it augments it with your synthetic generated images.